# Scan two variables in a do-while loop in c

Tags: c, do-while

I am trying to create a do-while loop that scans two variables but when I type "exit", I want the function to go out the loop. 
This is my code:

```
char var1;
char var2;
do {
    scanf("%s %s", &var1, &var2);
} while ("Some argument that I don't know")
```

I tried `(strcmp(&var1,'quit') != 0)` and things like that as argument but it doesn't work.

Comment: A char can  hold exactly one char, not a whole string of them.

Comment: Carefully read the manual on the `scanf` and note what it returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable type is wrong. It must be an **array of char** to hold a text string.

Use `strcmp` to check for "exit"

Something like:

```
char var1[32] = {0};
char var2[32] = {0};
do {
    scanf("%31s %31s", var1, var2);
}while ((strcmp(var1, "exit") != 0) && (strcmp(var2, "exit") != 0));
```

Another approach so that the program exits the first time someone inputs "exit" could look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
char var1[32] = {0};
char var2[32] = {0};
do {
    scanf("%31s", var1);
    if (strcmp(var1, "exit") == 0) break;
    scanf("%31s", var2);
    if (strcmp(var2, "exit") == 0) break;
    printf("%s %s\n", var1, var2);
}while (1);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: OK! I test that and now it works! Thanks! But is it possible to make it so when I write "exit" for the first time, the program goes out of the loop directly? Because I want to either give a "value" to the two variables or write "exit" and the directly go out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of your issues is that you're trying to scan a string into a char variable:

char var1  creates a new char variable, which can hold a single character at a time.

%s in scanf scans a string - a character *array*.

Initialising your variables as:

```
char * var1;
char * var2;
```

Will allow scanf to scan strings into them. Your *strcmp* line from before should probably work after that - though you'll need an additional condition if you want to check both variables.